# How to dynamically set an Angular JS page's Title?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, meta-tags

I have a running single-page AngularJS Web Application. To manage my routes, I'm using [**ui.router**](https://ui-router.github.io/). Here is the state for my Splash Screen:

```
  $stateProvider.state('splash',
      {
          url: '/',
          templateUrl: 'html/splash.html',
          controller: 'SplashCtrl',
          data: {
              meta: {
                'title': 'Splash Screen'
              }
          }
      }
  );
```

Did you notice that this state contains a `data.meta` object? That's because I'm using [**ngMeta**](http://vinaygopinath.github.io/ngMeta/#/) to populate the page's `<title></title>` tag. Everything works.

However, I want to the title to be dynamic, not static. I want to set/adjust it in the `SplashCtrl`. But I don't know how to do that. Can someone show me? In the HTML template, I address it like this: `<title>{{ngMeta.title}}</title>`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can inject ng-meta in your controller and then set meta tags dynamically as below

```
app.controller('YourController',["$scope", "ngMeta",function ($scope,ngMeta) {
    ngMeta.setTitle('Home page');
    ngMeta.setTag('description', 'This is the home page');
    ngMeta.setTag('keywords', 'angular,stack,nodejs');
    ngMeta.setTag('author', 'Tony ');
}]);
```

Comment: Can u show me how to do this injection from the controller please?

Comment: @AmadouBeye you missed a closing sqare bracket though.. :)

Comment: @SaqibAli updated ! Don't forget to accept this answer if it's worked for you ;)