# How to dynamically set and Angular JS page's meta og tags for Facebook sharing?

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, facebook, facebook-graph-api

This question is closely related to [**this one**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44060648/how-to-dynamically-set-an-angular-js-pages-title) I asked a couple of days ago.

I am building an angularJS web-application. I am currently trying to use the [**ngMeta**](http://vinaygopinath.github.io/ngMeta/#/) module to allow the web-app to produce dynamic entries for page title and for meta tags so that' Facebook will know to display an image, a title and description whenever a user posts a link from my web-app. I'm using [**Facebook's public-facing debugger**](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/) to help me troubleshoot this.

But it is not working for me. Here is the state I'm using for my web-app's Splash Page:

```
  $stateProvider.state('splash', {
          url: '/',
          templateUrl: 'html/splash.html',
          controller: 'SplashCtrl',
          data: {meta: {'title': 'XXXXXXXXXXXX',
                        'description': 'YYYYYYYYYYYY'}}});
```

Here is my controller:

```
myApp.controller('SplashCtrl', function($scope, ngMeta) {
    var self = this;
    console.log('self = ', self);

    ngMeta.setTag('description', 'DDDDDDDD');
```

Here is my [**index.html**](https://gist.github.com/saqib-zmi/88148f95954d5ef365daf9efe30e4aca)

Here is my template file, `splash.html` which is referenced in the state declaration:

```
<div ng-controller="SplashCtrl as splashCtrl">
    HELLO WORLD
</div>
```

Look what Facebook's debugger reports when I scrape this Splash Page (FYI, my private info has been scrubbed):
[image]

Why isn't the description I'm setting in SplashCtrl (`'DDDDDDDD'`) showing up in Facebook's scraper? How can I fix it so it does?

BTW, I have successfully initialized ngMeta using the `run()` block. I know it's working because when I load this page, the `<title>{{ngMeta.title}}</title>` from `index.html` correctly shows up as `AAAAA`.

So ngMeta.setTitle() is definitely working. Then how do I set and access the other properties like description, image, etc?

Comment: Have you Initialized ngMeta using the run block ?

Comment: Yes. I have. And I know it's working because when I load this page, the `<title>{{ngMeta.title}}</title>` from `index.html` correctly shows up as `AAAAA`

Comment: Hi, remove [description] in the state, you can't set 2 description for current state, it's one binding.

Comment: Maher, I did. However, that didn't make any difference. You can see the website yourself here: http://www.predictagram.com

Comment: The Facebook scraper does not care about any client-side JavaScript. All it cares about is the HTML code the server returns when the URL is requested; _that_ HTML code mus contain the OG meta data.

Answer (score 2):

All your meta tags are binding well, you can see it by inspecting your page

[image: screenshot of your website].

I think this facebook tools is reading the source code of your page instead of the initialised angular app(as if you do CTRL + U in chrome to see your source code, you will see that datas are not templating)

This does not matter for sharing content from your angular application. Facebook will take care to read the binding value instead of the scope variable

However if you want no scope variable from your source code,
 [This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16525048/6002163) answer could be a solution